# Container deployment fails because of invalid credentials (invalid_grant)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We have a deployment process in place using GKE for an application, but it was setup by another developer who has since left, and his account was removed. It now seems that a new deployment fails as a result:

[2016-01-24 21:02:30,489, INFO] ERROR: (gcloud.docker) invalid_grant

I have a rough idea on how everything works together (instance templates, instance groups, VMs, container clusters), and what has to change (the .boto file has to be regenerated from a new p12 file associated with an existing service account). However, I have no idea where I need to go to get access to that .boto file - does that file exist in the image? template? container cluster?

Could the instance template be associated to that ex-developer's account? And as a result the deploy to the container fails? Does the instance template to be re-created (assuming that it can't be edited)?

Help and direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems like a permission issue with Google Container Registry. Can you please email gcr-contact@ so we can gather more information to help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue!

On the build server, first run:

gcloud auth list

I noticed that ex-developer's credentials were still active. Then ran:

gcloud auth login

Paste the URL into a browser, and login with the email above, and then take the verification code presented in the browser, and paste into the commandline... and voila!